# Fill in missing column values in CSV using Vim

Tags: search, csv, vim, replace, format

I have a fairly large CSV file (366MB), that I need to edit in Vim so it can be inserted into a DB - i have it changed to a .txt file to open.

The CSV is in the format:

```
111111111,11,11
```

Followed by a newline and other records. But in some places it only has:

```
111111111,11
```

Meaning that SQL returns errors

Is there a way I can search and replace something like `anything,anything\r\n` with `anything,anything,0\r\n` - if you get my meaning? Hopefully maintaining the two values before
I wasn't sure what to search and have only just started using Vim for this, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a line with only one comma in it, search for *no comma, any number*, followed by one *comma*, followed by *no comma, any number*. In Vim's regular expression syntax, that's `[^,]*,[^,]*`. It still needs to be *anchored* to the full line with `^` and `$`.

Now `:substitute` all those with itself (`&`), and append the "missing column":

```
:%s/^[^,]*,[^,]*$/&,0/
```

Voila!

PS: Also helpful with manipulating CSV files: [csv.vim - A Filetype plugin for csv files](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=2830)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a little differently from @Ingo Karkat's solution.  Using the same pattern, I would find each matching line and append ",0" instead of replacing the entire line with itself followed by ",0".  There are two variants:

```
:%s/^[^,]*,[^,]*\zs$/,0/
:g/^[^,]*,[^,]*$/s/$/,0/
```

On your CSV files (and I agree that 366MB counts as "fairly large") you might notice that one of the three methods is a little faster than the others.

Comment: Luckily I only needed to go over them once, good to know for the future though!

Comment: Too bad.  I was hoping you would tell us whether there was a noticeable difference.